# XDocument Descendents Where Name Contains

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I may not be googling the right keywords, as I can't seem to find anything similar.

I have an XDocument that has descendents in different places like :

```
<country>
<addressCountry>
<idcountry>
```

Can I locate all descendants as in this mockup code?

```
XDocument.Descendents.Where(x => x.ToLower().Contains("country"));
```

How would I go about that?  Thank you for any and all help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want the *local name* part of the *name* of the element:

```
// Adjust this how you wish.
var comparison = StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase;
var elements = 
      doc.Descendants()
         .Where(x => x.Name.LocalName.IndexOf("country", comparison) != -1);
```

(This is a cleaner way of performing case-insensitive checks - it avoids the "Turkey" problem of lower-casing `I` to `ı` for example. It's annoying that there isn't an overload for `Contains` which takes either a `StringComparison` or a `StringComparer`, but such is life...)

Comment: With that, I get an exception: `'string' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Queryable.Contains<TSource>(System.Linq.IQueryable<TSource>, TSource, System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<TSource>)' has some invalid arguments`. Looks like you can't have a case insensitive `Contains` for strings (the easy way). I had to change it to: `var elements = xe.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName.IndexOf("country", comparison) >= 0);`.

Comment: @Corak: Thanks for having eagle eyes - I clearly haven't had enough coffee :) Have changed it to `!= -1` to hopefully be more obvious what it's guarding.

Answer (score 0):

```
myXDocument.Descendants("country")
```

Just take care of possible namespace problems...

Comment: That would not get `<addressCountry>` or `<idcountry>`. But OP want's to get those, too.